# Lazy loading (only Spring JPA on GET operation)

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, lazy-loading

I have entity structure Project->Task->Type. Project->Task OneToMany and Task->Type ManyToOne. Now if I have Lazy FETCH for both the relationships how should i fetch listOfTasks and getTypes for each Task in getProject / getAllProjects service method?

I read a bunch of articles etc but nothing helped me so far to streamline my understanding. I got the ManyToOne handling for getting Cs while reading Bs. But how to get Bs for A entity object with Join fetch.

Should I do `project.setTasks ( taskService.getTasksByProject() //repo method in TaskRepository )` or include repo method in `project.getTasks()` in model Project? second option seems to be hack with repo present all over to Model definition.

Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

```
Model Project
    List<Task> taskList (OneToMany)
    private List<Task> getTasks()
    { return this.taskList;}  

Model Task
    Type taskType (ManyToOne)

ProjectService
    @Transactional(readonly = true)
    public Project getProjectById(final Long projectId) {
         final Project project = projectRepo.findOne(projectId);
         //If I access project.getTasks() works ok but i want to access it outside of transactional. i.e. in controller method 
         //Should I do project.setTasks( taskService.getAllTasksByProjectId() ) which is repo method.
         return project; 
    }
```

Comment: Very hard to understand what you want given the total absence of code, and the contradictory descriptions. Why would A have several Bs if A->B is a ManyToOne? Post code. Use real entity names instead of A, B, C. Post an example method. Tell clearly what it should do, and describe which problem you're facing. Post what you tried, based on your reading of the reference documentation.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you for pointing it out. I have standard Spring data project with Lazy fetch for relationships mentioned. What I am looking for is best practice for handling lazy fetchs in case where I need to get Projects but also Tasks and Types for each task in project.

Comment: Then edit your question as I suggested.

Comment: I updated my q with right relationships and names. I am not looking for the code or direct solution. Its more of dev approach qs. I am not concerned with writing code myself just need an opinion of expert on topic if that is the right way to move ahead.

Comment: This is much too vague to be answered. It depends. And we have no idea of what these methods are supposed to do.